# Chrome debugger how to edit/skip inline script at (index) source file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I load a page from a site (it's not mine) and I want to bypass a broken ad blocker (it works regardless of whether the ad blocker works or not), it spoils further work on the page.
chrome debugger screenshot of bad script which is needed to be

[image]

I found the line of code that does this, it's marked with an arrow in the screenshot. I **already successfully** erased a similar code but on **another** page of the site and the site (at mine, client, side) **worked**, but that time it was written to a **separate .js** file which I have edited and ctrl+S and continue execution. And this time it is located in **(index)** file as **inline script**. I manage to add a breakpoint before executing the code, but I can't edit the content of (index) file in any way, or somehow skip the execution of this section with this inline script. Help me please.

Here is full script of section

```
<script>
    function getalladblocks() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(
            e) {
            e("#contentuy")
                .html(
                    "Please disable Adblock to proceed to the destination page."
                    ).css(
                    "display",
                    "inline-block"
                    ).css(
                    "margin-top",
                    "15px")
                .addClass(
                    "mtk alert alert-danger"
                    )
        })
    }
async function checkAdBlocker() {
    let e;
    return void 0 !== e ? e :
        await async function() {
            try {
                return fetch(
                        new Request(
                            "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", {
                                method: "HEAD",
                                mode: "no-cors"
                            }))
                    .then(
                        function(
                            t) {
                            return e = !
                                1
                        })
                    .catch(
                        function(
                            t) {
                            return getalladblocks(),
                                e = !
                                0
                        })
            }
            catch (t) {
                return console
                    .log(t),
                    getalladblocks(),
                    e = !0
            }
        }()
}
const usingBlocker = checkAdBlocker(); 
</script>
```

Comment: What's the full code? Enable pretty print so you see it properly on multiple lines. And then I'd recommend overwriting the function after is defined and before it ever gets executed, with `getalladblocks = () => {}` or something like that.

Comment: I updated question by adding code. And... Your advice works! Overwriting is the right decision! Before execution of **const usingBlocker = checkAdBlocker();** I executed in console **checkAdBlocker  = function() { }**